# How to build Android Quick bar Slider App

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, slider

I want to implement an application similar to the brightness setting slider in the quick drop down of the Android phone. This application will pass the slider value to the Kernel.

I am not looking for brightness setting app.  But app will place button on the "quick bar" and it has to be a slider. Also must be able to pass values to the kernel.

​Looking to get some help on this

Thank you

Comment: You can create a `TileService` to add a tile, but it will not be a slider. Otherwise, what you are describing is not an app, but rather a change to the system app that implements the notification drawer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can we write and load system app if we have root access? Or do we have to did through (rebuild) the whole OS to do this?

Comment: My guess is that this is not just a system app, but that is just a guess.